# How to access content library as guest user in experience builder

Tags: apex, lightning-experience, files, content, guest-user

in "VNSK" library i have some images that i use as URL for custom object and later i'm retrieving this object via SOQL in my LWC component

this works fine for manage library members (i have tried to add guest user too but it did not help), but when noone is logged in it does not work,

any help? maybe better place to storage images?

(photo: library / not logged user / logged user)

[image: library/nologged/logged]

Comment: So when none is logged in, you do not have access to pictures or to Custom objects at all ?

Comment: i have access to one object and its fields because my class (where i use SOQL) is defined as without sharing